# Make a form field selection values dependent on another field value

Tags: graph, acumatica, dac

I am editing the AP301000 screen, Bills and Adjustments, in a customization project.

I added two new fields to the form, which are both in the APRegisterExt class. 
1. PONbr
2. ReceiptNbr

When a user selects a PO number, I want the ReceiptNbr selection values to be restricted to only the receipt records which have the same PO number.

I tried using a PXSelector attribute on ReceiptNbr, but because the PONumber is in an extension class, I cannot use Current<> to access this field.

Any  ideas?

Answer (score 1):

On your second CustomField's Selector attribute definition use **Current<>** statement for filtering, see below:

```
#region UsrCustomField1
[PXDBInt]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="CustomField1")]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<DAC.Field>),
                     typeof(DAC.Field),
                     typeof(DAC.Field),
                     SubstituteKey= typeof(DAC.Field))]
public virtual int? UsrCustomField1 { get; set; }
public abstract class usrCustomField1 : IBqlField { }
#endregion



#region UsrCustomField2Dependent
[PXDBInt]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="CustomField2Dependent")]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<DAC.Field, Where<DAC.Field, Equal<Current<UsrCustomField1>>>>),
                     typeof(DAC.Field),
                     typeof(DAC.Field),
                     SubstituteKey= typeof(DAC.Field))] 
public virtual int? UsrCustomField2Dependent { get; set; }
public abstract class usrCustomField2Dependent : IBqlField { }
#endregion
```

Then on your ASPX file make sure you have added **CommitChanges=True** and **AutoRefresh=true** properties, see below:

```
<px:PXSelector runat="server" ID="CstPXSelector2" DataField="UsrCustomField1" CommitChanges="True" AutoRefresh="True" />
<px:PXSelector runat="server" ID="CstPXSelector1" DataField="UsrCustomField2Dependent" CommitChanges="True" AutoRefresh="True" />
```

Comment: If needed you can also add a Validate on your  usrCustomField2Dependent 
 in case the user fills in field 1, then field 2, but changes field 1 - I would assume you want field 2 to be invalid at that time. Ex: 
  [PXFormula(typeof(Validate<usrCustomField1>))]